# Unable to Give Full Control to SharePoint Online Add-in

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I registered an add-in on my SharePoint Online site collection by going to [Site Collection URL]/_layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx
Noted Client ID and Client Secret. Trying to give it FullControl here: [Site Collection URL]/_layouts/15/AppInv.aspx by entering the following XML:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">  
   <AppPermissionRequest Scope="Site Collection URL" 
    Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

On 'Do you trust the app page' it does not ask me to give it Full Control but only the following:
*Let it share its permissions with other users.
Let it access basic information about the users of this site.*

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site collection scope url should be `http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection` instead of your site collection url.

Read this article for more:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/add-in-permissions-in-sharepoint

The xml should be this.

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">  
   <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" 
    Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Amateur developer mistake lol.